# Inferring generic parameter type from a callback function

Tags: c#, api, generics, callback

I have a piece of code that currently looks like this:

Signature of the Subscribe method:

```
void Subscribe<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> action);

class Service { 
   int methodThatRequiresIntAndReturnsInt(int i) => i * 2;
}
```

In my mind it should be possible to extrapolate what the types for T and TReturn when trying to use the subscribe method, however compiler tells me that the types cannot be inferred from usage, meaning i end up writing this code:

```
Queue.Subscribe<int, int>(Service.methodThatRequiresIntAndReturnsInt);
```

My question is whether it is possible and if so how should the method signature/usage look so that it would be possible to use it without type hinting e.g.:

```
Queue.Subscribe(input => input * 2);
```

Current implementation is along the lines of this:

```
_commandSubscription.Subscribe<CreateUpdateCommand, bool>(Resolve<UpdateService>().CreateUpdate);
_commandSubscription.Subscribe<AddCommentCommand>(Resolve<UpdateService>().AddComment);
```

The implementations for the service methods are as follows:

```
public class UpdateService {

    public void AddComment(AddCommentCommand command) {
         // DO STUFF
    }

    public bool CreateUpdate(CreateUpdateCommand command) {
        // Do stuff 
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the return type of `Subscribe` method? is it `TResult`? you should return it, I believe

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
Queue.Subscribe((int i) => Service.methodThatRequiresIntAndReturnsInt(i));
```

In practice the subcribed function works equivalently and you avoid explicitly typing all generic arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this improved the code, i don't need to provide the return type at least.